# Google sites creation

Tags: java, google-sites

I am creating a sites by java programming using google sites API developer guide. I had easily created different type of pages as parent page and sub pages also. my problem is,I am not able to create a web page as parent page and file cabinet, announcement, list page as sub page. That's parent page and sub page is created as same not as different page. please tell me a solution.

Comment: What has this got to do with Java?

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript by any chance?

Comment: @crowne and @niko: I can't read the OP's mind, but googling "google sites developer guide" finds http://code.google.com/apis/sites/docs/developers_guide.html , which lists guides for two languages: java and python - no javascript.